# Cannot publish a list to a rostopic using a class in Python

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have created a class and defined a publisher in the `__init__`. i have defined a function in the class and would like to publish a list into the topic but it seems that the data doesn't get published at all. It works fine when I remove classes and just define a single function but I want to work this out using a class.
Here is the code,

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#from std_msgs.msg import String
import rospy
from trajectory_msgs.msg import JointTrajectoryPoint
import random

class TrialPublisher:

    def __init__(self):
        self.pub = rospy.Publisher('trialtopic', JointTrajectoryPoint, queue_size=10)
        self.node = rospy.init_node('talker', anonymous=True)

    def talker(self):
        #rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz
        action1 = [0.10972262,  0.46574646,  0.74584746, -0.79732597, -0.17833593, -0.74599963]
        action2 = [0.1372262,  0.40574646,  0.64584746, -0.69732597, -0.1633593, -0.7299963]
        action3 = [0.11972262,  0.46574646,  0.70584746, -0.73732597, -0.15833593, -0.73599963]
        action4 = [0.12972262,  0.46574646,  0.72584746, -0.72732597, -0.14833593, -0.74999963]
        action5 = [0.12972262,  0.46574646,  0.73584746, -0.71732597, -0.13833593, -0.8599963]
        action6 = [0.14972262,  0.46574646,  0.6584746, -0.70732597, -0.12833593, -0.44599963]
        action = random.choice([action1, action2, action3, action4, action5, action6])
        x  = JointTrajectoryPoint()
        x.positions = action    #rospy.loginfo(hello_str)
        self.pub.publish(x)
        
s = TrialPublisher()
s.talker
```

I get the error as,
WARNING: no messages received and simulated time is active.
Is /clock being published?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337689/cannot-publish-a-list-to-a-rostopic-using-a-class-in-python/) by [mkb_10062949](https://answers.ros.org/users/44036/mkb_10062949/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2019-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rospy.spin()` blocks forever and does not return. You probably want `rospy.sleep(1)` instead.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-11-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mkb_10062949](https://answers.ros.org/users/44036/mkb_10062949/) on 2019-11-15**:
Thanks for your answer, I tried it using a class but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay so I found out that I was missing a parenthesis while calling the function `talker()`

---

Originally posted by [mkb_10062949](https://answers.ros.org/users/44036/mkb_10062949/) with karma: 43 on 2019-11-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1